# How to place the HTML rectangualar box at the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have two queries as stated below:-

**1)** I want to move the blue colored rectangular box **(containing username and password text fields)** to the center of the page. I tried using **&nbsp** to change the location of the rectangular box but strange, it is not moving at all.Is there any parameter in HTML which can help me shift this box to the center of the page? Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

**2)** The **BORDER = 8** parameter is not working as here I want to set a dark black colored border around my rectangular box. Can anyone suggest what can be the cause of this issue?

To replicate the issue which I am facing, copy the below codes  in a .TXT file and save it as .HTML file. Open in IE or Firefox browser to see the issue which I am getting.

**Code:**

```
<html>
<form id="login" action="index.html">
<div style="width: 450px; height: 250px; background: blue;BORDER=8"><br/><br/><br/>
&nbsp;<strong>Username: </strong>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="userid" size="18" maxlength="18"/><br/>&nbsp;<br/>
&nbsp;<strong>Password : </strong> &nbsp; <input type="password" name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18"/>&nbsp;<br/><br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp 
&nbsp;</div><br/><br/>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide a demo page via http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although this is not a js-question:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: 225px; width: 450px; height: 250px; background: blue; border: 8px solid black"> content </div>
```

- position **absolute**, left 50% and margin-left: -225px (half width) will position the box in the middle of the screen.
- **border: 8px solid black** is the right way to define a border of 8px width

Answer (score 4):

if you only want to center horizontally try with: `margin:0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/P2rQK/

```
<div style="width: 450px; height: 250px; background: blue;margin:0 auto;">
    <form id="login" action="index.html">
        <strong>Username: </strong>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="userid" size="18" maxlength="18"/> 
        <strong>Password : </strong>&nbsp; <input type="password" name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form" />
    </form>
</div>
```

It is bad to use `&nbsp;` to position elements. also `<br />` is not a "clean" way.

Comment: All answers are correct..Thanks a lot guys!!that was helpful

Comment: thx, still helpful!

Answer (score 3):

If you want truly dynamic positioning, use the below which is not reliant on specifying dimensions. Critically it uses a CSS tabulated layout to do the position calculations. The border can be achieved by giving your `form` a `border:8px solid black;`

You should also move your styles out from being specified inline- and use CSS to control your layout instead of reliance on so much HTML (such as `&nbsp;`).

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/eSRQx/7/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <form id="login" action="index.html">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userid" size="18" maxlength="18" />
            <br />
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="password" name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
label {
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
    display:inline-block;
    border:8px solid black;
    width: 450px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background: blue;
}
input {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `margin: 0 auto;` to your blue box.

Look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6uhk9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="border-width:8px;border-color:red;border-style:solid;width:450px;height:1050px;background-color:gold;"> content </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using a lot more CSS and less use of the `&nbsp;` and `<br>`.

```
`    <html>
    <style>
        #login { 
            left: 50%;
            width: 200px;
            margin-left: -225px;
            position: relative;
        }
        div {
            width: 450px; 
            height: 250px; 
            background: blue; 
            border:8px solid #000;
            padding:20px;
        }

    </style>
    <form id="login" action="index.html">
        <div>
            <strong>Username: </strong>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="userid" size="18" maxlength="18"/><br>
            <strong>Password : </strong> &nbsp; <input type="password" name="pswrd" size="18" maxlength="18"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form" />
        </div>
    </form>
</html>`
```

Try playing around with margins to get the positioning correct.